# scipy.stats.pearsonr with lists of Decimals?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, decimal

Trying to run `scipy.stats.pearsonr` with two lists of `Decimal` is making `scipy` unhappy:

```
print type(signals)
print type(signals[0])
print type(prices)
print type(prices[0])

<type 'list'>
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
<type 'list'>
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>

correlation = stats.pearsonr(signals, prices)

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "commod.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "commod.py", line 69, in main
    correlation = stats.pearsonr(signals, prices)
  File "/home/.../venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 2445, in pearsonr
    t_squared = r*r * (df / ((1.0 - r) * (1.0 + r)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'Decimal'
```

Anybody run into a solution for this?

Comment: Convert everything to `float`?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but I'd like to avoid that as I'm working with price data, which (I believe) should always be treated in a precise format like `Decimal`

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the problem arises because the `pearsonr` function is trying to run arithmetic operations on float and Decimal, and python doesn't like that. You can, however, convert the Decimal list into floats -

```
stats.pearsonr([float(val) for val in signals], [float(val) for val in prices])
```

Even though in your comments you mentioned that you want to use Decimal for precise format, the floating point errors will hardly alter your results.